# Which values can be entered in a NOT NULL field SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, notnull

I was looking to an answer to this question and I wasn't able to find a precise answer. I did found some questions ([q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563251/can-i-insert-an-empty-string-in-a-not-null-field)) which asks whether a specific value could be entered.

I'm in a situation where I would like to enter a default 'empty' value which is still allowed in a `NOT NULL` field in my (postgresql) database.

I'm thinking about values like `''`, `""`, `undefined`, `null` which can be passed from a JAVA project in my case.
Currently I'm using a working solution with the empty String.

*Edit; Sidenote: For us this implementation it is a temporarily placed value which should eventually be replaced, for others (and for us aswel) it can be important to find missing, empty or wrong values in the database.*

Comment: You can enter a value that meets the column data type definition. There is no "undefined object" type in SQL like in *shudder* Java except a "SQL Variant". But I am highly afraid to recommend it to you because of the question you seem to be asking... which may result in your database being awful.

Comment: What is the actual question? Any other valid value based on data type is allowed, but not null. If empty string works then why change it? But why use any other value for empty than null?

Comment: What's wrong with using NULL? If your field can contain the concept of non-existence why not declare the field as nullable and use NULL to state that there is nothing there.

Comment: Seems like a bad idea. NOT NULL means a valid value is expected.

Comment: `""` or `undefined` are not valid values (constants) in SQL

Comment: So, you have a system that was designed to have a systematic means of representing missing information (`NULL`), restrict its use, and then start looking for a systematic means of representing missing information?

Comment: That is a `NULL` question  :-/